# style="background-color: #FF0000" not working in chrome or safari?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

I am making a html table in ruby for my project where I want to have background color on some cells. I tried "bgcolor" first which seems to have been deprecated and then I tried style="background-color: #FF0000" but nothing seems to work.

***My code:***

```
table = "<table class='sortable' id='components_table'>" +
            "<thead>" +
            "<tr class='all'>" +
            "<th>some-data1</th>" +
            "<th>some-data2</th>"  +
            "<th>some-data3</th>" +
            "</tr>" +
            "</thead>"

table += "<tr>" +
         "<td id='#{"some-data1"}'>" + some-data1 + "</td>" +
         "<td id='#{'some-data2'}'>" + some-data2 + "</td>" +
         '<td id="#{"some-data3"}" style="background-color: #FF0000">' + some-data3 + '</td>' 
table += "</tr>"
```

Is that the style="background-color: #FF0000" doesn't work in chrome/safari browsers? Is there any other way I can change the background color of the cell to display on Chrome/safari/mozilla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`style="background-color: #ff0000"` should work. You have `color="#ff0000"`. You are missing the `background-`

Comment: Sorry I was trying color as well since background-color didn't work for me. I will update it in my question. But yes, both didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Why have you switched to single quotes (') when trying to change the background-colour

Comment: Was trying it differently since it was not working with double quotes first. But it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I got where the issue was. It was something in my logic. style="background-color: #ff0000" works both on chrome and safari as well. Thanks for trying it out for me!

Comment: If you aren't using `color="#FF0000"` in your code, this should not be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using double quotes inside single quotes //without escape char

try this

```
table += "<tr>" +
     "<td id=\"#{'some-data1'}\">" + some-data1 + "</td>" +
     "<td id=\"#{'some-data2'}\">" + some-data2 + "</td>" +
     "<td id=\"#{'some-data3'}\" style=\"background-color: #FF0000\">" + some-data3 + "</td>" 
table += "</tr>"
```

Comment: This [looks like the solution](http://jsfiddle.net/sbg5skng/) to me. Look at the syntax highlighting in the OP. Downvoter, care to comment?